# Subtract 2 minutes from a unix timestamp

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

Could someone assist me on a timestamp issue.. how can I subtract 2 minutes from this timestamp?

```php
    echo 'Settings from database (octopus_import_employees):';
    $settings = get_settings('octopus_import_employees');
    var_dump($settings);

    echo 'Timestamp in human format (Started timestamp):';
    $started = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $settings['started']);
    var_dump($started);
```

`var_dump($settings);` gets an unix timestamp such as: 342534534

`var_dump($started);` converts it to a readable format such as: `2019-11-08 05:08:58`.

All help would be appreciated.

Comment: 342534534 this is dummy timestemp ?

Comment: Yes, @YasinPatel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timestamps are in seconds so you can subtract 120 seconds (i.e. 2 minutes) from it

```
$time = $settings['started'] - 120;

echo 'Timestamp in human format (Started timestamp):';
$started = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
var_dump($started);
```

Answer (score 2):

@YasinPatel solution is definitely the simplest for your situation. In situations where you don't have a unix timestamp input, one of these methods might be easier to use.

You could create a `DateTime` object from your timestamp using [`date_create_from_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and subtract 2 minutes from it, using either [`sub`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) or [`modify`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php):

```
$started = date_create_from_format('U', $settings['started']);
$started->sub(new DateInterval('PT2M'));
echo $started->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

or

```
$started = date_create_from_format('U', $settings['started']);
$started->modify('-2 minutes');
echo $started->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/lme48)

Comment: Thanks so much @Nick, let me give this a try.